# Can't figure out why my css sheet isn't showing. I've search this site and google

Tags: css

I've ran both my css file and index.html file through a validator and they're good. When I click on my index.html to open it in my browers (firefox) I see no styling. I've tried googling and looking through stackover flows question with no luck. I've emailed my professor but after 3 hours i'm hoping you guys might be able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

here is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Path of Light Yoga Studio</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="yoga.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
<header><h1>Path of Light Yoga Studio</h1></header>
<nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp; <a                  href="classes.html">Classes</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a> &nbsp; <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> &nbsp;
</nav>
<main>
    <h2>Find Your Inner Light</h2>

    <p> <span class="studio">Path of Life Yoga Studio</span> provides  all levels of yoga pratice in a tranquil, peaceful
    environment. Whether you are new to yoga or an experienced practitioner, our dedicated
    instructors can develop a practice to meet your needs. Let your inner light shine
    at the <span class="studio">Path of Light Yoga Studio</span></p>

    <ul>
        <li>Hatha, Vinyasa, and Restorative Yoga Classes</li>
        <li>Drop-ins welcome</li>
        <li>Mats, blocks, and blankets provided</li>
        <li>Relax in our Serenity Lounge before or after your class</li>
    </ul>

    <div>
        Path of Light Yoga Studio<br>
        612 Serentity Way<br>
        El Dorado, CA 96162<br>
        <br>
        <br>
        888-555-5555<br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</main>
<footer>

        Copyright &copy; Path of Light Yoga<br>
        <a href="mailto:Paul.Snowden@pcc.edu">PaulSnowden@pcc.edu</a>
</footer>
 </div>
</body>
```

and my css.

```
body    {   background-color: #F5F5F5;
        color: #3F2860 ;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;}

header  {   background-color: #9BC1C2;
        text-align: center;}        

h1      {   line-height: 200%;}

nav     {   font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;}

nav a   {   text-decoration: none;}

studio  {   font-style: italic;}

footer  {   background-color:#9BC1C2;
        font-size: 0.60em;
        font-style: italic;
        text-align: center;}

wrapper {   margin-left:  auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 80%;}
```

Comment: `studio` should be `.studio` and `wrapper` should be `#wrapper` in the CSS file.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this should work: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yoga.css">`

Comment: let me try and see if that helps

Comment: That did it, thanks so much. To help me better learn can you explain what the "type="text/css" does?

Comment: Well it is the "type" attribute to specify the media type of the <style> tag...  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks.